# Cannot set key of conference solution in manifest file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-apps-script-addon, gsuite-addons

I cannot set "key" property in manifest file of GSuit application

```
"conferenceSolution": [{
    "onCreateFunction": "createConference",
    "id": "messanger",
    "name": "Some messanger",
    "key": {
      "type": "addOn"
    },
    "logoUrl": "https://logos.com/some/logo123.png"
  }]
```

but on push, I get  error that:
`GaxiosError: "appsscript.json" has errors: Invalid manifest: unknown fields: [addOns.calendar.conferenceSolution[0].key]
    at Gaxios._request (C:\Users\iyano\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@google\clasp\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:85:23)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async OAuth2Client.requestAsync (C:\Users\iyano\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@google\clasp\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\oauth2client.js:350:18)`

Comment: Why are you trying to set it into the manifest file? What exactly are you trying to do? The conference solution key should be specified in `Code.gs`.

Comment: @ziganotschka, thanks for you answer. But where and how I can set it? I am used `Calendar.newConferenceSolution()` but I didn't find where I can set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Sample request of how to create an event with conference data in Apps Script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var calendarId = "primary";
  var resource = {
    "summary": "event with conference data",

    "end": {
      "date": "2020-04-10"
    },
    "start": {
      "date": "2020-04-10"
    },
     "conferenceData": {
      "createRequest": {
        "requestId": "123",

        "conferenceSolutionKey": {
          "type": "eventNamedHangout"
        }
      }
    }
  };
  var event=Calendar.Events.insert(resource, calendarId,{"conferenceDataVersion":"1"})
  Logger.log(event.id);
}
```

If it is for an Addon - I assume that [`type`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events) should be `addOn` instead of `eventNamedHangout`.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. But I get that error when I choose my 3p conference solution in messangers drop-down. Maybe you know how to fix that without sending request directly across standard workflow?

Comment: [Here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events) you can find information to the event resource with all possible parameters you can specify in your request).